# Bootstrap modal adding text

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to adding text `dynamically`. Please take a look at my script first.

```
<id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Progress</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
      aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:100%">Please Wait</div>
    </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

and i have this

```
$(".progress").html("<p class='pesanberhasil'>Upload File Berhasil</p>");
```

and here is my CSS

```
p.pesanberhasil
{
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

This part `<p class='pesanberhasil'>Upload File Berhasil</p>` showing up. But the text isn't `fit` Here is the screenshot

[[image: enter image description here]]

Sorry for my bad english.

Here is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/c0b2kbmr/

Well. I've fix this .

```
$(".progress").remove();
$(".modal-body").html("<p class='pesanberhasil'>Upload File Berhasil</p>");
```

but i thing there is other solution without `$(".progress").remove();`

Comment: can you creat a fiddle for this>

Comment: try to add a height to `.pesanberhasil` css like 40 or `50px !important`

Comment: i've put my script on jsfiddle. please see my udated question

Answer (score 0):

did you already remove the margin on **p** tag? Bootstrap have **10px** default  margin in **p** tag. Also try to **fiddle** this

Comment: i've put my script on jsfiddle. please see my udated question

Answer (score 0):

Add some padding top and padding bottom to the 
`<p class='pesanberhasil'>Upload File Berhasil</p>`. 
You can add padding properties in the class -pesanberhasil .

padding:15px 0px 15px 0px;

Answer (score 0):

Reduce **p.pesanberhasil** font-size. Bootstrap 3's **.progress-bar** default height size is **20px** and your **p** element has **padding** which is causing your text to not fit in a **20px** div.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the display properties of `.progress` and `.pesanberhasil` to table and table-cell respectively and then add padding if you want.

```
.progress {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.pesanberhasil {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```js
$(".progress").html("<p class='pesanberhasil'>Upload File Berhasil</p>");
```

```css
.progress {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.pesanberhasil {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Progress</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%;">Please Wait</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```